# Getting "XmlRootElement cannot be resolved to a type" error after upgrading GWT from 2.8.1 to 2.8.2

Tags: java, gwt

In order to fix the broken GWT drag and drop in Chrome 61, we decided to upgrade 
GWT since the fix is in GWT 2.8.2.

After upgrading, I got hundreds of following errors:

```
[ERROR] Line 7: XmlRootElement cannot be resolved to a type
[ERROR] Line 3: The import javax.xml.bind cannot be resolved
```

I tried to upgraded other dependencies to the latest version and got no luck.
Any solutions or suggestions are appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to add a dependency on that jar now, it is no longer part of GWT (and probably shouldn't have been to begin with, which is why it is gone):

Maven:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.0</version>
  <classifier>sources</classifier>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Gradle:

```
gwt 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.0'
```

---

EDIT: Correction, it looks like this might not be just related to updating GWT, but specific to Java 9 - no longer are these classes included in JDK 9, so you must actually have a dependency on the jaxb-api in your project.

Comment: Thanks, I found a [post](https://www.mail-archive.com/google-web-toolkit@googlegroups.com/msg105521.html) about this issue from gwt mail group earlier, but your solution and explanation is exactly right.

Comment: Ha, great, I actually copied it from there. Glad you've got it sorted.

Comment: @ColinAlworth: your solution works fine when packaging using maven indeed. The problem persists though, when I develop a GWT app using SuperDevMode (https://github.com/tbroyer/gwt-maven-plugin). The above error causes the GWT compiler to crash and the SuperDevMode doesn't even get started... Any hints on how to solve this?

Comment: when I added dependency It was still error that annotations are not resolved but when I removed classifier and scope tag it get fixed that error why this is so ?

Comment: what is mentioned by @KamtaSahu is working for me. Could someone explain the reason.

Comment: If you must remove the provided scope, then you are using it at runtime somewhere, and this probably isn't the same error. At that point, I can't really comment on why you don't need the sources jar.

Answer (score 6):

Using this dependency (added in your POM file) has solved the problem for me

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: It's basically the same as the answer 2 years ago, but I  had to remove `<classifier>` or/and `<scope>` to work, so your answer helped me.